# DynamoDB TTL fix strategy - set to wrong type (String and not Number)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We just realized that we have set TTL type on the DynamoDB table as **String** and not as a **Number**. The TTL field is named "ttl" unfortunately.

"ttl" was set to expire records that are older than 365 days.

This table has grown and is very very big... 26GB.

1. what is the quickest way to change the type of the "ttl" from String to Number?

Few thoughts that we had:

A. Change code so that when a "new record" is saved we set its "ttl" field to Number.
This works if you try it through the console! In this case, we would write a "clean up" job to go through previous records and fix the "type" to Number.

B. Create a new field "ttl_expiry" of type Number. So when "new record" is saved we set "ttl_expiry" and NOT the original "ttl" column. In this case, we would write a "clean up" job to go through previous records and "convert from string to number and copy" into "ttl_expiry" field.

2. what other strategies can we use to fix this TTL issue?

Is there a quick batch update we can do?

Ah yes, and we are using java :-)

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are willing to ignore the TTL on existing items and just enforce them for future items, it doesn't really matter whether you do A or B, because either way, you will have to read and write every single record in your existing table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way, you'd have to update all records in the table, which means you need to read and update them. That's going to be comparatively pricy and can't really be optimized if you're doing it online.

For DynamoDB it also doesn't really matter which of the options you're taking, it will only care about attributes that are called `ttl` and have the type Number (If you change the attribute name, it will look for that).

I'd be more worried about Java, it tends to be fussy with data types in the sense that it cares more about them than let's say Python. Option B may be more appropriate in this case and allows you to read "old" records without issues.

Shorter attribute names help you save on storage cost, so having `ttl` is probably preferable, but given the modest size of the data that's not going to be a significant number.

**Bottom line:** Either way can work, with Java the mechanical sympathy is probably higher with B), if you're optimizing for ongoing cost, go for A).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually what we have decided is to create a new table with the correct TTL type and all new records will be written to this new table. We will delete the existing 26GB table after 365 days and disable the read/write capacity and this should save on costs but I guess we'll be charged for 26GB storage?

Comment: Yes, you'll be charged for that, but realistically that's not going to be a significant amount of money for most businesses.